# Why can an abstract class not be sealed or static?

Tags: c#, abstract-class, static-classes, sealed

Why can an abstract class not be sealed or static?

And I am also confused about the question *[Why declare static classes as sealed and abstract in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268983/why-declare-static-classes-as-sealed-and-abstract-in-c)*.

Comment: Take a look at this answer from Michel Keijzers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9213911/540653

Comment: what is the confusion?

Comment: Abstract class can not be static and other side  says  declare  static class as abstract what does that mean ? @abhitals

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. `static` class cannot be marked `sealed` because it is made `sealed` by compiler by default.

   > Static classes are sealed and therefore cannot be inherited.
2. `static` class cannot be marked as `abstract`, because it would be pointless. `abstract` class makes sense when you want all derived classes to implement same part of the logic. But because `static` class cannot be derived there is no way other class will implement these gaps.

   > They cannot inherit from any class except `Object`.

Both quotes from [Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx).

C# specification is a little more detailed about that:

> **10.1.1.3 Static classes**
>
> A `static` class may not include a `sealed` or `abstract` modifier. Note, however, that since a `static` class cannot be instantiated or derived from, it behaves as if it was both `sealed` and `abstract`.

You can read what does it mean for class to be `sealed` or `abstract`:

> An abstract class cannot be instantiated directly, and it is a compile-time error to use the new operator on an abstract class

> The sealed modifier is used to prevent derivation from a class. A compile-time error occurs if a sealed class is specified as the base class of another class.

**Update**

And a word about an article linked in the query you mentioned ([Static Class Design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229038.aspx)). It's already stated in accepted answer from that question. If you read carefully you can see that:

> √ **DO** declare `static` classes as `sealed`, `abstract`, and add a `private` instance constructor **if your programming language does not have built-in support for static classes**.

.NET (so C# as well) do have built-in support for static classes, so you don't have (and even can't) to make your classes *pseudo-static* by marking it both `sealed` and `abstract`.

Comment: I have read that answer @MarcinJuraszek and I have created one sealed class **A** and create another sealed class **B** which extend or inherit *A* class and it without error how its possible if sealed class is not inherited ?

Comment: It's not. Try `public sealed class A { }` and `public sealed class B : A {}`. You'll get *'`B`': cannot derive from sealed type '`A`'* error message.

Comment: thank you @MarcinJuraszek ,your explanation is great I got my answer ,I am just unaware of **static** internal definition like it behaves like **sealed** and **abstract**  because Static class is not instantiated like *abstract* class and can not be inherited like *sealed* class .Thank you